# How the comma works when I list things on a sentence?

Tags: grammar

Every time I write something like:

> "She is interested in surfing, snowboarding and skateboarding"

The grammar checker suggests me to fix and add a comma before the end, becoming:

> "She is interested in surfing, snowboarding, and skateboarding"

And the grammar checker explains:

> The serial comma (also called the Oxford comma) is the last comma
> before coordinating conjunction and the final item in a series. Its
> use is considered a matter of style and is cause for much debate. Many
> style guides require the serial comma, and a few advise against it.
>
> There are times when it must be used to avoid confusion or ambiguity.
> For the sake of consistency, we recommend always using the serial
> comma. However, consult your style guide if you are uncertain.
>
> Depending on the context, a missing serial comma may cause ambiguity.
> Are the brothers named Adam and Jane?
>
> Ambiguous:    We have received RSVPs from my brothers, Adam and Jane.
>
> Clear:    We have received RSVPs from my brothers, Adam, and Jane.
>
> Incorrect:    Make sure to pack towels, sandals, sunscreen etc.
>
> Correct:  Make sure to pack towels, sandals, sunscreen, etc.

I feel this strange, in Portuguese we never use comma in this situation to remove the ambiguity, moreover, **it is wrong to use it**. Should I use in English?

Comment: As your grammar checker says 'its use is considered a matter of style'. I wouldn't use an Oxford comma in your example, but others might advise you to do so.

Comment: As the grammar checker presented it, I also always put a comma before the conjunction. But as Kate said which in turn was said by the grammar checker, _matter of style_.

Comment: It's entirely up to you, but whether you choose to use the Oxford comma or not make sure you are consistent in your usage throughout.