# Leave out "the" or not

Tags: definite-article

In the following two sentences, can "the" be left out or not?

- Sentence A:

  1. You should particularly focus on the pronunciation, the stress, the intonation, the rhythm of each word in the audio.
  2. You should particularly focus on pronunciation, stress, intonation, rhythm of each word in the audio.
  3. You should particularly focus on the pronunciation, stress, intonation, rhythm of each word in the audio.
- Sentence B:

  1. Please read the whole dialogue script thoroughly until you grasp it completely, including the new words, the grammar and the meaning.
  2. Please read the whole dialogue script thoroughly until you grasp it completely, including new words, grammar and meaning.
  3. Please read the whole dialogue script thoroughly until you grasp it completely, including the new words, grammar and meaning.

Comment: I prefer A3, but it needs _and_ before _rhythm_. (NB it's _particularly_.)  Similarly B3, although I'm not quite sure whether you mean 'the meaning of the new words' or 'of the whole script'.

Comment: a 1, 2, 3 and b2

Answer (score 1):

A2 is awkward. A1 and A3 are natural, but would be used in slightly different situations:

- A1: Each noun's having its own "the" emphasizes the individual words.
  This would be appropriate if they hadn't already been mentioned recently.
- A2: Without an initial "the", it emphasizes a list of words.
  This sounds awkward, as the "of each" seems to apply to the list and not the individual words.
- A3: The initial "the" is implied for each word in the list.
  The "of each" then naturally attaches to each individual word.

The main problem with B2 and B3 is that the word "new" might be read as applying to "grammar" and "meaning" too.
This could be avoided by reordering: "grammar, meaning, and new words".

P.S. It's a good idea to put a comma before the "and", as that is where one would naturally pause when speaking.
Omitting it can sometimes cause ambiguity and confusion. ([grammar - How the comma works when I list things on a sentence?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/262239/how-the-comma-works-when-i-list-things-on-a-sentence))

Comment: So, if "new words" is put after grammar and meaning like "including grammar, meaning and new words", is it all right for sentence B2 to leave out "the"?

Comment: @questionguy, yes, "Please read the whole dialogue script thoroughly until you grasp it completely, including grammar, meaning, and new words." would be fine.

Comment: Thank. you so much for your explanation and help.